# WPF get string from resources throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I've been trying to get a string from resources file:

```cs
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Properties.Settings));
var recent1 = resourceManager.GetString("recent1");
```

But I got an exception:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any
> resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
> culture.  Make sure "ProCodeX.Properties.Settings.resources" was
> correctly embedded or linked into assembly "ProCodeX" at compile time,
> or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
> signed.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You can use `var str = Properties.Resources.recent1;` to obtain the string value instead. When adding a string to the resources the template uses `internal static` signature for the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retrieve string from *.resx* file don't no need to create the `ResourceManager` class instance. The template uses `internal static` signature for the property when adding a string to the resources. Therefore the resource can be obtained directly:

```
var recent = Properties.Resources.recent1;
```

And here's an example how do get the string by creating instance of the `ResourceManager` when required to obtain resource for specific culture:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("WpfApp11.Properties.Resources", typeof(Properties.Resources).Assembly);
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
var recent1 = rm.GetString("recent1");
```

For additional information see [ResourceManager.GetString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring?view=net-5.0).